# Keeping only the rows that satisfies a condition with respect to an another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So right now I have a Pandas DF like this:

```
Name     Year      Label

Jeff     2018        0
Jeff     2019        1
Matt     2018        0
John     2018        0
Mary     2018        1
Mary     2019        1
```

I want to keep all the rows for each unique name that has both Years 2018 and 2019.

The result should look something like this:

```
Name     Year      Label

Jeff     2018        0
Jeff     2019        1
Mary     2018        1
Mary     2019        1
```

Matt and John were removed because they didn't have both 2018 AND 2019.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Does your year column only have these two years? Or is your actual problem to find names that are present in all groups? The solutions are different, so please be specific.

Comment: the columns ONLY has 2018 and 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `crosstab` select all the name with two year , then using `isin`

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.Name,df.Year)[[2018,2019]].eq(1).sum(1)==2
df.loc[df.Name.isin(s.index[s])]
Out[463]: 
   Name  Year
0  Jeff  2018
1  Jeff  2019
4  Mary  2018
5  Mary  2019
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` + `transform`:

```
m1 = df.Year.eq(2018)   
m2 = df.Year.eq(2019)

df[m1.groupby(df.Name).transform('any') & m2.groupby(df.Name).transform('any')]

  Name  Year
0  Jeff  2018
1  Jeff  2019
4  Mary  2018
5  Mary  2019
```

---

Generalising:

```
years = [2018, 2019]
M = [df.Year.eq(year) for year in years]
df[np.logical_and.reduce([m.groupby(df.Name).transform('any') for m in M])]

   Name  Year
0  Jeff  2018
1  Jeff  2019
4  Mary  2018
5  Mary  2019
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an inner [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on 'Name', once selecting both years independently in `df`, to get the 'Name' that have both years, then use `isin`:

```
df.loc[df.Name.isin(df[df.Year == 2018].merge(df[df.Year == 2019],
                                              on='Name',how='inner').Name)]
   Name  Year  Label
0  Jeff  2018      0
1  Jeff  2019      1
4  Mary  2018      1
5  Mary  2019      1
```